# PyUsb in IronPython

Tags: usb, ironpython, pyusb

I'm trying to detect a device using PyUsb.
I have succeeded in python2.7 but in ironpython (ipy.exe) it dosen't finds the device. 
I have tried with imported modules and installed ones. 
any idea?

Comment: You need to write more about what you have tried and how did you do to successfully communicate with the device in Python2.7.